# Change the window title text color to match the theme

Tags: gnome, themes, window

I'm using gnome-shell. I've tried gnome-color-chooser and gnome tweak, but gnome-color-chooser does not work on GTK3 and, as far as I know, nor does it work on GTK2; the option isn't in gnome tweak. I have tried using dconf-editor, but I'm not sure what I'm doing. I've tried editing these files but I am not exactly sure what I should be changing.

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance-Blue/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance-Blue/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance-Blue/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

I am trying to make my Firefox Nightly window and the other windows to have the same blue color (they are currently white) as the date/time and the weather extensions.

I am using the Ice Cream Sandwich shell theme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe this will benifit those who are interested in customizing their setup and/or looking for an alternative to gnome-color-chooser. Maybe gnome-color-chooser will be rewriten and implemented in System Settings?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at wrong place.

Window titles are not drawn by GTK, it is drawn by Metacity in Gnome Shell (by Compiz in Unity, etc...)

I haven't tried but the right file is placed under metacity folder in a theme's main folder. The name is metacity-theme.xml (or something like that)

And the code block that will be changed :

```
<draw_ops name="draw_title_text_normal">
    <title color="#333" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)+1"/>
    <title color="#333" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)-1"/>
    <title color="#333" x="9" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
    <title color="#333" x="11" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
    <title color="#dfdbd2" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="draw_title_text_unfocused">
    <title color="#333" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)+1"/>
    <title color="#333" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)-1"/>
    <title color="#333" x="9" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
    <title color="#333" x="11" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
    <title color="#807d78" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
</draw_ops>
```

Comment: Mutter is a product based on Metacity. _Mutter = Metacity + Clutter_